# system.MissingMethodException for simple AWS SNS class on both Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Pulling my hair out.  Xamarin Forms app.  .Net Standard.  Used to work.
I instantiate a class I wrote:

```
aws = new Aws()
```

that has a simple constructor:

```
 private AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient();
```

It gets `system.MissingMethodException` on the `aws=new Aws()` complaining that `AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient` doesn't exist

I have:

1. deleted `obj/*` and `dev/*`
2. removed and reinstalled the `AWS Nuget packages` (including the    dependencies on SNS)
3. cleaned the project and rebuilt

This happens on both Android and iOS (real devices)

Comment: "used to work" ... did anything happen?  VS update?  Nuget update?

Comment: have you tried manually adding the .dll into the project by right clicking "references" ?  It's not ideal but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, vs update, and nuget update.  I was also having some other weird problems with the SNS code, but backed that all out and then got this.

Comment: If I right click references in the iOS project, I don't see any of the Nuget packages

Comment: Did you delete the bin folder too?  I've found when the references get all whacked out in VS the bin folder makes a bigger difference.  Maybe delete bin/obj, remove the nuget, clear your temp folder, restart vs, then re-add the nuget

Comment: I'll try that.  Probs tomorrow as that isn't a quick fix

Comment: did you restart your computer after you updated VS?  An acquaintance recently encountered some issues due to a lack of restart after it updated.

Comment: Oh well.  I did that.  Same issue.

Comment: Didn't restart the computer.  It's a mac; usually doesn't do anything.  I can try it though.